# How do I get access to the variables / methods in static files in Node.js + Expressjs at the server-side without using POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, serverside-javascript

More Specifically, I have a blob initialized and processed in a .js file in the 'public' (static folder) folder. Since that has been processed at the client-side, I want to know if there's a way I can somehow get access to the blob at the server-side without using a POST request. The file we talking about has been processed and is stored in a variable in a static file (script.js), Now I need to upload that variable/blob onto the Database. But, in a static file, I don't have access to the Database and can't even export the variable to the server. How do I get access to that variable which is within the static file? Someone, please edit if they have understood my requirement.

What my program does is that it records audio through the microphone of the client And that audio file has to be **uploaded onto the Database**. Now, I can add the functionality of 'Download' for the client and let the client download the file and then the client uses `<input>` tag to send a POST request to the server, But, now the client can upload any audio file into that input tag, Basically, this is a web app for live monitoring students writing exam, So that don't they don't cheat I capture their audio and save it to the DB. Please refer to my folder Structure for more details and then read the question again.

My Folder Structure:

```
   --DBmodels
       ---AudioModels.js
       ---ImageModel.js
   --node_modules
   --public
       ---scipt.js (This contains the code for audio processing)
   --views
       ---test.ejs (Main HTML page)
   --index.js (server file)
   --package.json
```

Here is a small diagram for reference :
[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQF37.jpg)

And here is my Folder Structure :
[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJcA8.png)

One way of doing is this to download it on the client-side and then ask the client to upload but that doesn't work for me due to some reasons.

Here is my script.js, But I don't have access of the variables such as `chunk_audio[]` on the server.

```
   const chunks_audio = [];

    mediaRecorder.onstop = async function (e) {
        console.log("DONE WITH AUDIO");
        const blob = new Blob(chunks_audio, {
            'type': "audio/ogg codecs=opus"
        });
        const audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        console.log(audioURL);
        var link = document.getElementById("downloadaudio");
        link.href = audioURL;
        var audioMIMEtypes = ["audio/aac", "audio/mpeg", "audio/ogg", "audio/opus", "audio/wav"]

        const audio = blob
        const audiodb = new AudioSchema({
            name : "Audio"+Date.now().toString()[5]
        });
        saveAudio(audiodb,audio)
        try{
            const new_audio = await audiodb.save();
            console.log("AUDIO UPLOADED" + new_audio);
        }catch (err){
          console.log(err);    
        }
        function saveAudio(audiodb, audioEncoded) {
            if (audioEncoded == null) return;
            console.log("before parse: " + audioEncoded);
            const audio = JSON.parse(audioEncoded);
            console.log("JSON parse: " + audio);
            if (audio != null && audioMIMEtypes.includes(audio.type)) {
                audiodb.audio = new Buffer.from(audio.data, "base64");
                audiodb.audioType = audio.type;
            }
        }

// module.exports = chunks_audio; (This doesn't work for obvious reasons)
```

Here is my server file `(index.js)` , I tried to use POST request where the user posts the audio file after it gets downloaded, But the user could post any other file in the `<input>` tag, So that doesn't match with my requirement:

```
  var audioMIMEtypes = ["audio/aac", "audio/mpeg", "audio/ogg", "audio/opus", "audio/wav"]

  app.post('/', async ( req, res, next)=>{

        const audio = blob   // 'blob' is a variable in script.js , Hence don't have access here 
        const audiodb = new AudioSchema({
            name : "Audio"+Date.now().toString()[5]
        });
        saveAudio(audiodb,audio)
        try{
            const new_audio = await audiodb.save();
            console.log("AUDIO UPLOADED" + new_audio);
        }catch (err){
          console.log(err);    
        }
        function saveAudio(audiodb, audioEncoded) {
            if (audioEncoded == null) return;
            console.log("before parse: " + audioEncoded);
            const audio = JSON.parse(audioEncoded);
            console.log("JSON parse: " + audio);
            if (audio != null && audioMIMEtypes.includes(audio.type)) {
                audiodb.audio = new Buffer.from(audio.data, "base64");
                audiodb.audioType = audio.type;
            }
        }
  })
```

Comment: you first want to download the file from the server and then upload the same file back to the server??

Comment: @marzelin I think you misunderstood me. The file we talking about has been processed and is stored in a variable in a static file (script.js), Now I need to upload that variable/blob onto the Database. But, in a static file, I don't have access to the Database and can't even export the variable to the server. How do I get access to that variable which is within the static file.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, the question is confusing. You say: "_my program ... records audio at the client-side_". Don't you then have the file in JS already? Just post the blob or buffer or in what ever format the file is. If you want to save it to the local system, just use a link with an data URI, `data:application/octet-stream; ...`.

Comment: @Teemu I need to save the audio file onto the Database, WITHOUT using a POST request.

Comment: so you have some base audio file hard-coded in your script and then a user modifies that file in some way. What you want is a way to send that file to the server, yes?

Comment: You can't send anything to the server without a request. But if you've the file already in a JS variable, you can post it with AJAX without user intefering the data.

Comment: @marzelin Totally, I need to send that file to the server (index.js), from the server I can upload it to the DB without a problem.

Comment: if the data you want to send is already stored in some javascript variable, use `fetch` to POST it (send data to a server) asynchronously (in the background).

Comment: @Teemu TY, I'll look into it. I would be very grateful if you elaborate on it.?